# Android: how to shift a Bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I would like to "shift" a Bitmap by a certain x and y offset.  By shift, I mean, If I have a 300x500 bitmap, and I shift it by a y offset of -50, I would expect every pixel to move up 50 pixels, and a 300x50 pixel rectangle to be blank, along the bottom of the Bitmap.  The below code works great if shiftX and shiftY are negative, but doesn't work at all for positive values.  I have no idea why?

```
Rect srcRect = new Rect(-shiftX, -shiftY, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
Rect destRect = new Rect(srcRect);
destRect.offset(shiftX, shiftY);

Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

I've tried many different versions of this.  It seems that trying to translate a Bitmap with a positive y always produces garbage.  In this simpler example, a negative shiftY gives expected behavior, but a positive shiftY gives a garbage result:

```
 Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
 bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, shiftY, null);
```

*Update. This is solved by the below code.  However, this is not memory efficient.  Any suggestions for a better solution?

```
Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
Bitmap tempBitmap = mBitmap.copy(CONFIG.ARGB_8888, false);
bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(tempBitmap, 0, shiftY, null);
```

Comment: `doesn't work` means what exactly? What do you get?

Comment: produces a seemingly garbage result

Comment: why do you create a new canvas?

Comment: the only new canvas is the one shown above, the one I create from mBitmap, to paint into mBitmap.

Comment: every drawing method should have a canvas as parameter, so you don't need to create a new one... as long as you draw on a SurfaceView like I expect it. You could try this tutorial series I have written: http://www.droidnova.com/android-3d-game-tutorial-part-ii,328.html

Comment: sorry, totally misread your question as "WHEN do you create a new canvas".  I create a new one, to draw into the bitmap.  my goal is to shift the bitmap, the way to do this is to draw the bitmap into itself, which can be accomplished by wrapping it in a canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this with your code.
I have tried it with an offset of 50 and -50 and both works as expected.

My code inside the drawing method:

```
// negative value: -50
Rect srcRect = new Rect(-(-50), -(-50), mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
Rect destRect = new Rect(srcRect);
destRect.offset(-50, -50);

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

or with positive:

```
// positive value: 50
Rect srcRect = new Rect(-50, -50, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
Rect destRect = new Rect(srcRect);
destRect.offset(50, 50);

canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect, destRect, null);
```

Comment: when you draw with the positive value, have you already initialized the bitmap to have some content? I think the issue is trying to overwrite pixels which have already been written.

Comment: the drawBitmap method with the rect read the pixels from the bitmap and draw them on the destRect, so there shouldn't be an already written pixel issue. Can you provide a bit more code?

Comment: I updated with a solution that works.  Because this solution works, I think the problem is that when I try to draw back into a bitmap, it's drawing over a pixel which then needs to be read later on, which isn't an issue if drawing in the opposite direction.  My solution is bad though, becasue it creates a 2nd bitmap, which doubles the memory usage.

Comment: I got exact same issue, when scrolling down it garbles the screen using your code Warren. For my code see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775093/how-to-update-off-screen-bitmap-in-a-surfaceview-thread

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution ...

```
canvas.translate(dx, dy);

canvas.draw....();
```