# How to scroll off screen memory bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scroll, surfaceview

Using below code to scroll
I have a Surfaceview thread and an off canvas texture bitmap that is being generated (changed), first row (line), every frame and then copied one position (line) down on regular surfaceview bitmap to make a scrolling effect, and I then continue to draw other things on top of that. Well that is what I really want, however I can't get it to work even though I am creating a separate canvas for off screen bitmap. It is just not scrolling at all.

I other words I have a memory bitmap, same size as Surfaceview canvas, which I need to scroll (shift) down one line every frame, and then replace top line with new random texture, and then draw that on regular Surfaceview canvas.

Here is what I thought would work;

My surfaceChanged where I specify bitmap and canvasses and start thread:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    intSurfaceWidth = mSurfaceView.getWidth();
    intSurfaceHeight = mSurfaceView.getHeight();

    memBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    memCanvas = new Canvas(memCanvas);

    myThread = new MyThread(holder, this);
    myThread.setRunning(true);
    blnPause = false;
    myThread.start();
}
```

My thread, only showing essential middle running part:

```
@Override
public void run() {
  while (running) {     
    c = null;
try {
    // Lock canvas for drawing
    c = myHolder.lockCanvas(null);                  

    synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
        // Scroll down off screen canvas and hopefully underlying bitmap bitmap
        Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight - 1);
        Rect dst = new Rect(0, 1, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight);
        memCanvas.drawBitmap(memBitmap, src, dst, null);

        // Note scrolling up like this works fine
        // Rect src = new Rect(0, 1, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight + 1);
        // Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight);
        // memCanvas.drawBitmap(memBitmap, src, dst, null);

        // Create random one line(row) texture bitmap
        textureBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgTexture, 0, rnd.nextInt(intTextureImageHeight), intSurfaceWidth, 1);

        // Now add this texture bitmap to top of screen canvas and hopefully underlying bitmap
        memCanvas.drawBitmap(textureBitmap,
                intSurfaceWidth, 0, null);

        // Draw above updated off screen bitmap to regular canvas, at least I thought it would update (save changes) shifting down and add the texture line to off screen bitmap the off screen canvas was pointing to.
        c.drawBitmap(memBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        // Other drawing to canvas comes here


    } finally {
        // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
        // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
        // inconsistent state
        if (c != null) {
            myHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
}       
}
```

For my game Tunnel Run, https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zubima.TunnelRun, right now I have a working solution where I instead have an array of bitmaps, size of surface height, that I populate with my random texture and then shift down in a loop for each frame. I get 50 frames per second, but I think I can do better by instead scrolling bitmap.

Comment: complete off-topic, but your app description in the market is full text, no paragraphs, no nothing... you should structure it! The first thought was: tldr

Comment: Good suggestion, added paragraphs thanks, however not sure what you mean by "full text...no nothing". This is a text only field, I can't add images to this.

Comment: True, but your text formatting was pretty ugly. I don't want a complete "how to use/play" guide in the description. Think of it much more like an advertising text. Summarize some cool features in a list, make the reader interested in your game.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to draw a bitmap on top of itself, something which has never worked on Android AFAIK. I fell into this exact hole with my first game, a side-scroller called Mole Miner.

The problem is very simple: the drawBitmap() is, in essence, a special kind of memcpy() in which bytes are always addressed *forwards*. Which is fine, and uses L1 cache optimally, etc, but you obviously hit a problem if the source and destination areas (a) overlap, and (b) source address < dest address.

(Real implementations of memcpy(), by the way, check for this possibility and do the copy backwards if necessary. Canvas.drawBitmap() does not do this.)

The workaround I used for Mole Miner was to have *two* off-screen bitmaps, and switch between them on alternate frames. But that was in 2009 and these days I'd probably not use scrolling at all.

Comment: Yeah figured it was a bug/bad implementation. I'll try the two off-screen bitmaps and switch between them later today and if it works I credit you for the answer, thanks!

Comment: If you're only ever scrolling in one direction (down), you could change this so you draw the bitmap upside-down and scroll *up* instead. You won't hit the problem if dest < source.

Comment: Perhaps I am unable to correctly visualize this, but that does not seem to be work. The tunnel in my game is decreasing in width over time. Imagine on one screen where tunnel goes from max width on bottom to min width in to an inverted V, scrolling down would animate this perfectly. Mirroring bitmap and again on one screen tunnel would go from max width to min width, it would look like a right side up V, where new bitmap material (line) would be refreshed in bottom ond then scrolled up, that animation seems to be to be totally off. Please correct me if I am wrong, thanks!

Comment: Ok Reuben I awarded you the bounty for explaning why it would not work, and although you provided a work around with two bitmaps, I don't think that is going to speed up my code any more. I was able to optimize a bit more in other ways and right now on my HTC EVO 4G I get 52 frames per second

Comment: 52fps ought to be enough for anybody. :)  Re. the upside down idea, what I meant was to store the bitmap logically upside-down... change 'memCanvas.drawBitmap(textureBitmap, intSurfaceWidth, 0, null);' to draw on the *bottom* line rather than the top, and then change the scrolling code so you are copying one pixel row *up* rather than one row down.  Finally you change your c.drawBitmap() to use a matrix so it draws the bitmap upside-down... which will of course seem to display it right way up (and scrolling *down* as expected).

Comment: Ok with the added matrix I understand, thanks I'll try when I get a chance

Answer (score 0):

There is a drawBitmap function within canvas with the following signature:

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint);
```

You can make your dst the size of the canvas, and your src can be set up to be new

```
 Rect(0,offset,width,height+offset)
```

You can then increment offset every frame and get a smoothly scrolling bitmap in your view.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I had already tried that, see my code change above as it does not fit here, but essentially it scrolls the bitmap the wrong way and reversing offset to a -1 does not make it scroll down

Comment: In your example, I think you're source and destination may be backwards. Source is the area of the bitmap you're looking at and Destination is the area on the display.

Also, what was your code for scrolling down?

Comment: Ok I understand with my added comments it may seem confusing, so let me revise original code and get rid of additions

Comment: This is how I would logically believe using drawBitmap Rect Src and Dst should be written to take current(Source) bitmap from first row down to one above bottom, and move that down one position, to (Destination) row one;

Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight - 1);
Rect dst = new Rect(0, 1, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight);
MemCanvas.drawBitmap(memBitmap, src, dst, null);